# What are these SMD components from a KEB inverter?

Tags: voltage

We found SMD component marked A1 in a KEB inverter. Is this a diode or a BJT?

[image: picture is attached]

Comment: Please ask a question, do you want all those parts identified? Can you provide dimensions?